# Setup Site in IIS cant be Displayed in Browser

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8

I setup a new Site in the IIS8. I've gone trough the setup wizard and placed the Files on the Path i referenced in the Wizard.

Even though when i want to access it in the Browser with the Hostname i entered it says that the page cant be displayed.

It's all local so i dont need to access it from another location.

Any clues what i might have forgotten?

I already checked [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site) to look if i forgot something but i didnt see anything

Comment: Did you setup DNS rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to make an entry in the hosts file.
Because of that i wasn't reachable.

Make the entry and it works fine.